# Controlling for covariates in fixed effects regression

Tags: regression, panel-data, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model

I have a panel dataset of students with their test scores and certain characteristics like student gender and parents' education. Let's call the main regressor of interest "x". If I control for student fixed effects, their fixed characteristics should become superfluous, yes? But I notice that the coefficient on x is considerably different if I control for the fixed characteristics along with student fixed effects, as opposed to only including student fixed effects. Shouldn't the coefficient on x be the same in both cases? What could be going on? Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: The only two covariates you have are gender and parental education?

Comment: @ThomasBilach These are the only covariates for fixed characteristics, yes

Comment: Is software returning estimates for the student characteristics that are fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I control for student fixed effects, their fixed characteristics should become superfluous, yes?

Correct.

Adjusting for any additional *observed* qualities/characteristics of your students in presence of the student fixed effects is not necessary, not to mention meaningless. In fact, the observed *time-constant* factors are completely redundant with the student fixed effects. That being said, your model shouldn't be returning estimates for any these *fixed* covariates.

> But I notice that the coefficient on $x$ is considerably different if I control for the fixed characteristics along with student fixed effects, as opposed to only including student fixed effects. Shouldn't the coefficient on $x$ be the same in both cases?

They *should*.

Any of the presumably *fixed* attributes of students are completely collinear with the student fixed effects. Software would invariably drop these redundant regressors; in other words, most software packages will exclude the *time-invariant* variables without any additional work on your part. As for why the results are "considerably" different, it's hard to say without seeing your data. Here is what I suggest:

1. Inspect the raw data to see if the observed student level characteristics exhibit any time variation. I'm not sure how you're "controlling" for time-constant student characteristics in the presence of student fixed effects. You're not actually controlling for anything. In essence, you're adjusting for something that can't be estimated. If, for example, gender, sex, personality, and/or parental education are truly stable features, then they're redundant regressors; you gain nothing by adjusting for them in the presence of the student fixed effects.
2. Check to see that you're actually estimating the student fixed effects properly. Again, the more popular software packages such as R, Python, and Stata will exclude gender and/or parental education for you—assuming they are, in fact, time-constant *fixed* factors—so you'd be comparing two models that are identical in terms of the number of parameters estimated. Including a full set of dummy variables for all students will suffice, but many canned routines now exist to help you estimate the student effects. Ensure you're estimating the fixed intercepts appropriately.

I *suspect* the observed student characteristics do exhibit some variation over time, hence the discrepancy you're observing. But even if the variables are somewhat sluggish in terms of their time variation, I wouldn't expect the results to be considerably different. You may have to quantify what "considerable" means in the context of your study.

And don't assume you can reliably measure all "stable" student level attributes. The student fixed effects will adjust for all *fixed* characteristics specific to your students—even those you haven't thought of!

I hope this answer is helpful. Try diagnosing the problem yourself. If you're still stuck, post a small subset of your data and code and we can help you further.

Comment: Wonderfully answered, Thomas! It has been very helpful to me, and my problem has been solved. Thank you so much!